# How would I change this shader code to change the axis it causes the object to rotate around?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, unity3d-shaders

I'm playing around with the code in [this Unity sample game](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/endless-runner-sample-game-87901) to find out how to transform objects with shaders. The game uses shaders to curve the world, and one of those shaders also causes objects to rotate around their y-axis. I'd like to modify it to rotate an object around it's z-axis instead.

I've tried swapping the z's and y's, but while that does get the cylinder I'm using for this experiment to rotate around the z axis, it also causes the cylinder to stretch. Only changing rotVert.z to rotVert.y causes the cylinder to spin on it's side at a 45 degree angle. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Here's the code which causes the object to rotate around the y-axis:

```
float4 rotVert = v.vertex;
rotVert.z = v.vertex.z * cos(_Time.y * 3.14f) - v.vertex.x * sin(_Time.y * 3.14f);
rotVert.x = v.vertex.z * sin(_Time.y * 3.14f) + v.vertex.x * cos(_Time.y * 3.14f);

o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(rotVert);
```

Comment: Could you leave the rotate around y code the same but add a rotation matrix to all the vertices to rotate the whole object after the spin?

Comment: I have no idea what any of that means apart from leaving the code alone, but I'll look it up.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this is very simple. You also need to modify the value of x.

```
            float4 rotVert = v.vertex;
            rotVert.y = v.vertex.y * cos(_Time.y * 3.14f) - v.vertex.x * sin(_Time.y * 3.14f);
            rotVert.x = v.vertex.y * sin(_Time.y * 3.14f) + v.vertex.x * cos(_Time.y * 3.14f);

            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(rotVert);
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. While it does cause my cylinder to spin on the correct axis, it stretches out into a differently shaped cylinder and has a weird 2D effect to it as it spins.

Comment: you might want to disable dynamic batching, either globally in your build settings or using the shader https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html. The batching combines the objects together, moving the center of the mesh to the origin